# Framework for the resultant symmetry of the combination of two symmetry groups?

Tags: group-theory

I am a chemist and not a mathematician, so I hope you can forgive me for my ignorance.

I've been thinking about a more formal way of understanding how to go about predicting the symmetry groups of molecular orbitals that are formed by the addition of two atomic orbitals.

To make that less vague, we can consider how chemists think about something like $O_2$. Without going into the details, there are two atomic orbitals that participate. They are identical and they are the 2p atomic orbitals - they have C2v symmetry (think like dumbbells or a pinched balloon) and when they combine they combine, they join either end to end or lobe to lobe (image: [representative diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5geq5.png)).

We classify the molecular orbitals in terms of their inversion symmetry - either symmetric with respect to inversion or asymmetric with respect to inversion (gerade or ungerade, respectively).

What I am interested in is knowing if anyone knows of a formal way to look at how the combination of symmetry groups produce other symmetry groups? I'd be happy with links to resources or something that comes to mind, not just an immediate solution to my problem.

Thank you

Comment: I looked for "combinations of symmetry groups" and found [point groups](https://geo.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Geology/Mineralogy_(Perkins_et_al.)/10%3A_Crystal_Morphology_and_Symmetry/10.4%3A_Combinations_of_Symmetry_Elements%3A_Point_Groups), but this might not be helpful.

Comment: Have you heard about the works of Jean Sivardiere https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/Jean-Sivardiere-85087442 ? He has written a very interesting book, full of applications "La symétrie en mathématiques, physique et chimie" (in french, has it been translated into english ?). I stongly advise it.

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie and DietrichBurd